# Event binding with buttons

Tags: python, button, tkinter

So i am creating a Sudoku game, and have generated a 9x9 grid of buttons. There are two difficulty levels - easy and hard. When a difficulty level is selected, numbers randomly generate on some of the buttons. The user then clicks on the empty buttons to change/set a number (each click increased the number by 1). However, the user can also change the generated numbers. Is there any way in which i can stop this. I managed to stop this by adding an if statement in my button generator, however when i added difficulty levels and separated the code into functions, i am no longer able to stop this.

Here is my button generator code:

```
def ButtonGenerator():
    for row_index in range(9):
        for col_index in range(9):
            if (row_index in {0, 1, 2, 6, 7, 8} and col_index in {3, 4, 5}) or \
                    (row_index in {3, 4, 5} and col_index in {0, 1, 2, 6, 7, 8}): #Colours a group of 3x3 buttons together to differentiate the board better.
                colour = 'gray85'
            else:
                colour = 'snow'
            btn = Button(frame, width = 10, height = 5, bg=colour, font=font1) #create a button inside frame
            btn.grid(row=row_index, column=col_index, sticky=N+S+E+W)
            global buttons
            buttons.append(btn)
```

Here is my leftclick event function:

```
def LeftClick(event):
    next_value = " 123456789 "
    try:
        current_value = next_value[next_value.index(str(int(event.widget['text']))) + 1]
    except ValueError:
        current_value = "1"

    event.widget.config(text=current_value, font=font1)
```

I have also attempted at creating a function which stops the numbers with pre-generated values from being changed by the user, however it does not work. Any ideas why??

```
def Checker():
    for row in range(9):
        for col in range(9):            
            for btn in buttons:
                if btn.cget("text") != "":
                    btn.bind("<Button-1>", LeftClick)
                else:
                    btn.config(font=font2)
                break
```

Comment: `Easy()` and `Hard()` have almost the same code so you could do one function and run with different arguments ie. `Level(easy)`, `Level(hard)` - or event you could keep data in dictionary `data["easy"] = ...` and then you can run it as `Level( data[difficulty] )`

Comment: instead of `if btn.cget("text") == "1" or ...` you could do shorter `if  btn.cget("text") != "":`

Comment: why do you unbold font after solving if you want to keep bold font ? Or maybe use colors.

Comment: I dont do it deliberately furas - a different array is printed (solved version) and therefore it cant tell out the pre-generated numbers from the user-entered numbers

Comment: I have adjusted the question a little to try be more specific

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't resolve your problem but it shows how I would organize data and code - and maybe it helps you to resolve problem.

First: I keep data in dictionaries so I can use easily get `data["easy"]` or `data["hard"]` (the same with `solved["easy"]`) or using variable `data[difficalty]` and `solved[difficalty]`

Next: for empty button I use `0` instead of `""`. And I use own field in button `b.value` to keep this value. Next I can easily calculate next value (modulo 10) and put empty string when value is 0.

At start I create board with empty buttons (`all_buttons`) and use function to reset buttons parameters using `zip(all_buttons, data["easy"])`. This way I can easily change difficalty.

```
import tkinter as tk

data = {
    "easy": [
         [8,0,0,0,4,0,6,7,0],
         [0,3,0,6,7,0,5,0,8],
         [0,7,2,0,0,0,0,3,4],
         [1,0,3,7,0,4,8,0,5],
         [0,6,5,0,1,8,4,9,0],
         [0,4,8,0,5,6,0,2,0],
         [5,9,0,4,2,0,0,0,0],
         [2,0,7,0,3,0,1,0,6],
         [3,0,4,0,6,0,2,0,9],
    ],

    "hard": [
        [0,8,0,3,0,5,0,1,0],
        [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
        [0,0,3,2,0,0,6,0,0],
        [0,0,7,0,0,0,0,9,8],
        [8,0,2,0,5,0,4,0,3],
        [4,1,0,0,0,0,2,0,0],
        [0,0,4,0,0,8,9,0,0],
        [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
        [0,9,0,7,0,6,0,8,0],
    ],
}    

solved = {
    "easy": [
         [8,5,1,9,4,3,6,7,2],
         [4,3,9,6,7,2,5,1,8],
         [6,7,2,1,8,5,9,3,4],
         [1,2,3,7,9,4,8,6,5],
         [7,6,5,2,1,8,4,9,3],
         [9,4,8,3,5,6,7,2,1],
         [5,9,6,4,2,1,3,8,7],
         [2,8,7,5,3,9,1,4,6],
         [3,1,4,8,6,7,2,5,9],
    ],
    "hard": [
        [2,8,6,3,4,5,7,1,9],
        [1,4,5,6,9,7,8,3,2],
        [9,7,3,2,8,1,6,4,5],
        [3,5,7,4,6,2,1,9,8],
        [8,6,2,1,5,9,4,7,3],
        [4,1,9,8,7,3,2,5,6],
        [6,3,4,5,1,8,9,2,7],
        [7,2,8,9,3,4,5,6,1],
        [5,9,1,7,2,6,3,8,4],
    ],
}

def left_click(widget):
    ''' process button click '''

    # get next value (modulo 10)
    widget.value = (widget.value+1) % 10

    # if zero then put empty string
    if widget.value == 0:
        widget['text'] = ''
    else:
        widget['text'] = widget.value

def create_empty_board(master):
    ''' create board with empty buttons '''

    # create black lines
    master['bg'] = '#444'
    master.columnconfigure(3, minsize=3)
    master.columnconfigure(7, minsize=3)
    master.rowconfigure(3, minsize=3)
    master.rowconfigure(7, minsize=3)

    all_buttons = []

    for r in range(11):
        # skip rows to create black lines
        if r in (3, 7):
            continue
        row_buttons = []
        for c in range(11):
            # skip columns to create black lines
            if c in (3, 7):
                continue
            b = tk.Button(master, text='-')
            b.grid(row=r, column=c, sticky='we')
            row_buttons.append(b)
        all_buttons.append(row_buttons)

    return all_buttons

def reset_board(all_buttons, local_data):
    ''' reset buttons on board without creating new buttons '''

    for row_buttons, row_sudoku in zip(all_buttons, local_data):
        for b, v in zip(row_buttons,row_sudoku):
            # create unstandard variable to keep current value on button
            b.value = v

            if v == 0:
                b['text'] = ' '
                b['command'] = lambda but=b:left_click(but)
                #b['fg'] = 'black'
                b['bg'] = '#ddd'
                b['state'] = 'normal'
                b['disabledforeground'] = 'black'
            else:
                b['text'] = v
                b['command'] = None
                #b['fg'] = 'blue'
                b['bg'] = '#cce'
                b['state'] = 'disabled'
                b['disabledforeground'] = 'blue'

def check_buttons():
    ''' compare buttons with `solved` '''

    local_data = solved[difficalty]

    for r, (row_buttons, row_sudoku) in enumerate(zip(all_buttons, local_data), 1):
        row_ok = True
        for c, (b, v) in enumerate(zip(row_buttons,row_sudoku), 1):
            if b.value != v:
                print('wrong row: {}, col: {}, button: {}, expected: {}'.format(r, c, b.value, v))
                row_ok = False
        if row_ok:
            print('OK row:', r)

def change_difficalty(level):
    ''' change difficalty and reset board '''

    global difficalty
    difficalty = level

    reset_board(all_buttons, data[difficalty])

# --- main ---

difficalty = "easy"

root = tk.Tk()

board = tk.Frame(root)
board.pack()

all_buttons = create_empty_board(board)

reset_board(all_buttons, data[difficalty])

b = tk.Button(root, text="Easy", command=lambda:change_difficalty("easy"))
b.pack()

b = tk.Button(root, text="Hard", command=lambda:change_difficalty("hard"))
b.pack()

b = tk.Button(root, text="Check board", command=check_buttons)
b.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

[image]

Comment: Your code uses OOP, which i am unfamiliar with and would like to stay away from for this task. Have you any ideas how i could stop the pre-generated buttons being changed by the events?

Comment: my code doesn't use OOP - I don't create any `class`

Comment: if you have problem with code then use `print()` to display values in variables and informations which part of code is executed. It is called "print debugging". Maybe you execute code in wrong place - ie. maybe you bind `LeftClick` in wrong moment. Or you run many times function which bind funcction so it may change behavior. Or maybe you have to unbind `LeftClick`. I use `command=` instead of `bind()` to assogn `left_click`and I can set `command=None` to unassign `left_click`

Comment: BTW: there is document PEP8 which describe how to format python code - one of rule is using `CamelCaseNames` for class names - like `LeftClick` -
 so your code looks like you use OOP ;)

Comment: CamelCaseNames is basical programming ettiquette - it has nothing to do with OOP

Comment: CamelCaseNames is ettiquette but in Python it is prefered for class names - even StackOverflow knows this and uses light blue color to highlight class names. There are even tools like pylint, pyflake which tread CamelCaseNames as class. Even some IDEs know this rule and shows warrnings. See: [PEP8 - Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)